# php $fopen error

Tags: php, linux, fopen, die

I run

```
lynx -dump 'http://k.tr.com/1234.php?MSISDN=************&USERNAME=****&PASSWORD=****&MESSAGE=TEST'
```

To write to the file 1234.txt; However Im getting the error can't access file which is defined in a statement within the 1234.php file as

```
$fp=fopen("/var/log/logfiles/1234.txt","a") or die ("cant access file");
```

How do I resolve this? error? The file has permissions 644;

I needed to create a copy of files in main server onto back up server. so I ran scp; but when i check file permissions for the same file on main server, i see their different from the back up server which shows bothe the Uid and Gid as me; these details on main server are:

Access:(0644/-rw-r--r--) Uid:( 33/www-data) Gid:( 0/ root)

ive tried altering to chmod 654, 777 and 655 and im getting the same error.

Comment: Enable error reporting and don't use `or die`

Comment: try chmodding the file, too: `chmod($file,777);` and after `fclose()` `chmod($file,644);` if you created the file with another user, try `chown :users 1234.txt` on the command line, most users are member of the default group, so they'll then be allowed to chmod it

Answer (score 0):

If the web server is running as the same user that has access to /var/log/logfiles you can set file permissions to 755, other wise you need 777.

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting a permission "a" to write to a file and your file has write permission for owner only.

Are you running the script as the user that created a file?

If not, do so. If you can't, change the permission of a file for others (the last octal) or for a group (second octal) your user that executes the script, belongs to.

So, try with `chmod 654` or `chmod 655` on `1234.txt`

Comment: I needed to create a copy of files in main server onto back up server. so I ran scp; but when i check file permissions for the same file on main server, i see their different from the back up server which shows bothe the Uid and Gid as me; these details on main server are:                                                                          Access:(0644/-rw-r--r--) Uid:( 33/www-data) Gid:( 0/ root)                                                                            ive tried both chmod 654 and 655 and im getting the same error.

Comment: I've searched and realized the problem arose on the UID and GIDs. I've just learnt about using both chown and chgrp to edit that and severything is up!! thanks rachel for leading me to look at file owner.